# perl + identify if param is empty value from ARG

Tags: perl

when I run the following script.pl script with no arguments:

```
./script.pl
```

I do not get the message `No arg`. Why? How to identify if `$param` is a null value or empty value, same as `[ -z` from ksh?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $param = $ARGV[0];
if ($param = "") {
    print No arg;
} else {
    print arg: $param;
}
```

Comment: `$#ARGV == -1` is the easiest. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV

Comment: but if ARGV[1]; is null or ARGV[2]; how to compare param with ..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's not Perl. Where did you learn that syntax? So much is wrong with it.

1. `$param = ""` assigns an empty string to `$param`, that's not what you want.
2. null is spelled [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) in Perl.
3. To compare strings, use the [`eq` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).
4. You must [quote](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) strings: `print "No arg"`

Much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
if (@ARGV) {
    print 'have parameters';
} else {
    print q{don't have parameters};
}
```

Comment: but if I have ARG1 and not ARG2 I get the don't have parameters?

Comment: I nearly made that same suggestion, but I'm guessing the OP wants to extend to handle different numbers of arguments, and then testing the length of @ARGV isn't quite so tidy.

Comment: Just try it and see. When you pass any parameters on the command-line, `@ARGV` is filled with values and the program goes into the first branch.

Comment: can you give me example for that THX

Comment: why need to print q{don't have parameters}; and not print "don't have parameters"  ??

Comment: @lidia: there is more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example to illustrate it a bit better.

```
if( $#ARGV == -1 ){
    print "No arguments passed.\n";
} else if( $#ARGV == 0 ){
    print "One argument passed.\n";
} else {
    print $#ARGV +1 ."arguments passed.\n";
}
```

I like using "scalar @ARGV" as this represents number of elements in an array. $#ARGV, instead, is the index of last element in the array. This is why it is off by one. *If $[ (this is a special variable that sets the starting index of Perl arrays.) was set to 1 and not 0 (the default), then $#ARGV would not be off by one for our purposes. I would not mess with $[ as it is a global. Changing may break a lot modules.*

```
my $argument_count = scalar @ARGV;
if( $argument_count == 0 ){
    print "No arguments passed.\n";
} else if( $argument_count == 1 ){
    print "One argument passed.\n";
} else {
    print "$argument_count arguments passed.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, it seems people found my previous answer mis-leading, so here's another try, more directly this time.

The test you're looking for is `defined`:

```
my $param = $ARGV[0];
if (defined $param) {
    print "arg: $param\n";
} else {
    print "No arg\n";
}
```

If there weren't enough parameters to fill in `$ARGV[0]` (or other later elements) the value in that position will be `undef`, so the `defined` test will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

if param is empty you can auto make a param val:

```
$ARGV[0] || 'yourParam';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's convenient snippet to make a script abort with an error if no arguments are passed:

```
if (not defined $ARGV[0]) {
    print STDERR "Error: missing parameter. Usage: perl $0 <required-parameter>\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

(There are more compact and more verbose/robust ways to write this, but as a Perl novice, I found this to offer a good balance of clarity and conciseness.)