# perl + @ARGV + print syntax

Tags: perl

1. How to print the number of arguments from @ARGV
2. according to the following script why its important to print

like

print q{don't have parameters};

And not as

print "don't have parameters"; ??

lidia

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl 
    if (@ARGV) { 
     print ......
    } else { 
    print q{don't have parameters}; 
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what the actual question is. Do you want to know what "q" means? You don't understand why the code works? Is the code not working for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl + identify if param is empty value from ARG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341703/perl-identify-if-param-is-empty-value-from-arg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the number of elements in any array in perl:

```
print scalar(@ARGV);
```

Using `q{}` OR single quotes `''` means that a string will get quoted but NOT interpolated, meaning any variables you have inside will not have their actual values. This is a faster way to create strings than with double quotes `""` or `qq{}` which WILL interpolate variables in the string.

Comment: Giving the OP a link to the manual would have been helpful here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Answer (score 0):

moreover, **print q{}** is a shorthand for :

```
 print 'don\'t have parameters'
```

double quotes mean your string gets interpolated. ie : perl analysis it to retrieve 
variable values.
simple quotes won't. No unrequired analysis -> faster, less memory/cpu/whatever usage